# mongoose countDocuments multiple keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have setup a Node get request to return the count of the keys in my database. However atm it returns the count of one key. I'd like to know how to add more keys to count. So instead of only counting Medium, I'd also like to count Small and Large.

```
    registerRoute.route("/countDocuments").get(function (req, res) {
   Sweatersizes.countDocuments({ sweatersize: "Medium" }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

Thanks!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query

- you can use group, and sum them seperatly

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IaaDUPztQPY)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": "$sweatersize",
    "count": {"$sum": 1},
    "sweatersize": {"$first": "$sweatersize"}}},
 {"$unset": ["_id"]}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Aggregation framework and `group` pipeline:

```js
registerRoute.route("/countDocuments").get(function (req, res) {
   Sweatersizes.aggregate([
     {
       "$group": {
         "_id": "$sweatersize",
         "total_count": {
           "$count": {}
         }
       }
     }
    ], function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(result);
      }
   });
});
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HS8j_O1DrTr)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Appreciate it. How can I create an response outcome for instance like: Small: 0, Medium: 10, Large: 1

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it again?

Comment: Im sorry for the late reply! When I do a GET request I get the following:

{
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 15952,
    "codeName": "15952"
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the both of you! This is de code that eventually responded how I wanted it to:

```
registerRoute.route("/countDocuments").get(function (req, res) {
  Sweatersize.aggregate([
    {
      $group: {
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        sweatersize: { $first: "$sweatersize" },
      },
    },
  ])
    .then((result) => {
      res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```